# Run a Script 5 Minutes after startup

Tags: python, temperature

I'm doing a project in home automation and it contains a temperature sensor i.e DSB1820 and a gas sensor MQ2 coupled with an MCP3008 ADC.
Using RPI2 with Jessie.
now, the script which contains 2 python programs,

1st : A python Program which Plots temperature graph using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) service.

2nd : A python program which sends an email alert to the user if the MQ2 Gas sensor value is above the set threshold value.

both these programs need internet to perform their tasks, and the problem with using crontab here is, it runs these on Boot giving me an error of no internet connection.

what i want is a script which contains these 2 programs and allow them to run once the Pi has fully booted up and connected to my wifi/lan , to which i set a time limit of 5 mins, can be manipulated later

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apologies. First SuperUser Post, @DavidPostill yes i have tried Crontab service but if always starts the script @ boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implicit title question can be answered simply by

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

, where `script.sh` starts with `sleep 5m`. In more general terms you'll want a program which starts as soon as possible, and then does:

```
while true:
    stuff = get_some_stuff_from_the_internet()
    if stuff is not None:
        break
    time.sleep(internet_check_interval_seconds)
use_stuff_to_do_stuff(stuff)
```